# After installing opencart3* journalv3 showing HTTP ERROR 500, how to solve?

Tags: php, http, opencart-3, journal

> Unknown: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in /home/unmuktopathsala/public_html/open/system/library/journal3/options/parser.php on line 296

> Unknown: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in /home/unmuktopathsala/public_html/open/system/library/journal3/options/parser.php on line 296

> Unknown: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in /home/unmuktopathsala/public_html/open/system/library/journal3/options/parser.php on line 296

> Unknown: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in /home/unmuktopathsala/public_html/open/system/library/journal3/options/parser.php on line 296

> Unknown: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in

Comment: I think you are using PHP8 and OpenCart code is not ready for it yet. _See [change log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)_

Comment: Thanks for your reply using PHP 7.3 (ea-php73)

Comment: Ok so what instruction is on line 196 of that file?

Comment: Unknown: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in /home/unmuktopathsala/public_html/open/system/library/journal3/options/parser.php on line 296.   another thing I saw right now that is when I am using the default theme site working properly

Comment: can you please come to resolve my issue through any desk? I'll be pleased

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "journal3/template/journal3/category_grid.twig" is not defined in "journal3/template/journal3/module/categories.twig" at line 8

Comment: category_grid.twig" is not defined in "journal3

Comment: I asked you to look at that script and show us the `explode()` command on line 296, I dont need you to repeat the error message for me I see those